# Load models via bin files in webgl?

Tags: javascript, models, webgl

I see an example where the data was in text inside an array, i seen another where someone loads the model through ajax with json.

Is there a way to load the files via binary? i dont feel like loading a 1mb model via 4mb json

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible to load binary files.

http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/05/reading-exif-data-with-javascript.html

But the problem is after that. That you need to know what format it is in. And extract everything from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery Binary Ajax](http://blog.vjeux.com/2011/javascript/jquery-binary-ajax.html), or for new browsers, [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_xmlhttprequest#Receiving_binary_data)

Answer (score 1):

If file is compressed with gzip then json size is almoast same as binary file size.

Anyway you can use [binary loader](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/98a83b2429f640973bd9098949f905f6647688de/examples/js/loaders/BinaryLoader.js) from three.js if you really need it.